# How can I align right, left divs in a content div at the same top-level?

Tags: css

```
#textblock{
     width: 260px;
     height: 100%;
     position;
     border: 1px solid #999999;
     padding: 0 5px;
     float: right;
     font-size: 95%; 
     background-color: #FEF4CC;
}

#brevillestandard{
    padding: 8px 0 0 5px;
    height: 80px;
    Width: 61%;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the problem that they're not lining up even? First I'd change your top margins and padding to be the same for both divs.  They won't line up as is.

textblock currently has 0px top margin & padding.

brevillestandard has 13px top margin & padding.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking how to make them line up at the top, make the margin the same. The first one's top margin is inherited (probably `0px`). The second one has a top margin of `5px`.

Comment: Thank you. Tried another aproach